# Метод photos.getWallUploadServer — Unknown method passed

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

Делал пост изображений на стену. Но не работают вызовы VK API:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var flashVars:Object;
    public var VK:APIConnection;
    public var viewer_id:Number;
    public var mpLoader:MultipartURLLoader;

    public function Main()
    {
        flashVars = stage.loaderInfo.parameters as Object;
        VK = new APIConnection(flashVars);
        viewer_id = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.viewer_id;           
        test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onwall);
    }

    public function onwall(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        VK.api("photos.getWallUploadServer", {uid:viewer_id}, onComplete, onError)
    }

    public function onError(r:Object):void
    {
        txt.appendText("Error\n");
    }

    public function onComplete(r:Object):void
    {
        txt.appendText(r.upload_url);
        var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(508,300);
        bmpData.draw(mymc);
        var jpgStream:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(89);
        var ba:ByteArray = jpgStream.encode(bmpData);
        mpLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
        mpLoader.addFile(ba, "photo.jpg", "photo", 'image/jpg');
        mpLoader.load(r.upload_url);
        mpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendPicToServerHandler);
    }

    public function sendPicToServerHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        var answer:String = mpLoader.loader.data;
        txt.appendText(answer);
        var data:Object = JSON.decode(answer);
        txt.text = String(data.hash);
        VK.api("photos.saveWallPhoto", {server: data.server, photo: data.photo, hash: data.hash}, wallComplete, wallError);
    }

    public function wallError(r:Object):void
    {
        txt.appendText(r.error_msg);
    }

    function wallComplete(r:Object):void
    {
        var post_id='post1';
        var post_message='dwwdawdaw';
        VK.api('wall.savePost', {wall_id:viewer_id,post_id:post_id,photo_id:r.id,message:post_message}, photoPosted, ErrorPost);
    }

    public function ErrorPost(r:Object):void
    {
        txt.appendText(r.error_msg);  // Вот тут выдает Incorrect signature: sid & secret authorization
    }

    function photoPosted(data: Object):void
    {
        VK.callMethod('saveWallPost', data.post_hash);
        txt.text = "LOADED";
    }
}
```

Может быть я где-то ошибся?

---

**Добавлено**

Заменил на другой метод с фотками. В FlashVars добавил параметры из документации — дебагер говорит вот что:

> {"error":{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method passed: Session can be expired, revoked by user or connected with different IP address","request_params":[{"key":"uid","value":"66748"},{"key":"sig","value":"525426689d54fb6e579e73c2252b486c"},{"key":"v","value":"3.0"},{"key":"api_id","value":"1888171"},{"key":"format","value":"JSON"},{"key":"sid","value":"7e22c25d7fece88f2316553937ff24f43e1073ca28e8b4302e65db35fa"},{"key":"method","value":"photos.getWallUploadServer"}]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем нашел проблему, но как решить, не знаю (кстати, взял другой метод):

```
var photo_id= "photo76260130_265939539";
VK.api('wall.post', {owner_id:viewer_id,message:post_message,attachment:photo_id}, photoPosted, ErrorPost);
```

Вот так работает, но `photo_id` он должен получать как ответ от предыдущего `wall.savePost`, но `r.id` ничем не равен.

Comment: Мне нужен ответ из photos.saveWallPhoto (а именно ид картинки). А дальше заюзать как параметр в wall.post

Comment: Так немогу дебажить я через контакт.) У меня Флеш Профессионал только стоит. Но если вывести на экран r.id (то что мне нужно) прога остановится. (Да, все ответы выводятся через r, смотрим выше где я например брал из ответов url)

Comment: Скачать и поставить flash builder. Насчет остановки программы - бред какой-то.

Comment: А через ФБ уже как браузер дебажить?

Comment: Да, через браузер, флешка будет запускаться внутри браузера, в настройках дебага нужно будет создать еще одно Web Application со ссылкой на вк сайт с апликухой, после каждого изменения прила нужно опять аплоадить на вк ...

Comment: В ответе сервера дата оказалась массивом, если вот так читать то работает data[0].id

Comment: Это через fb?

Answer (score 0):

Что именно не работает? Как Вы это определили? Нужно:

- дебагом проверить наличие вызовов как таковых;
- при вызове проверить правильность отправляемых переменных;
- че та тут (`var data:Object = JSON.decode(answer);`) меня гложут сомнения, пойду проверю, смотрели дебагом экземпляр data после джейсон декодера?

Comment: фотка на стену загрузилась !



альбом - Фотографии на моей стене

Comment: Так а в чем проблема почему у меня не работает?)

Comment: права у приложения есть на загрузку ? на доступ ? включи всё что там есть

Comment: Есть. В Фотографии на моей стене поялвется а пост на стене нет.

Comment: нууу ... еще раз, тестовый проект в FB, для нормального дебаггинга на вк

Comment: Проблемы так и не нашел. Incorrect signature: sid & secret authorization.Я подозреваю что не преедается параметр VK.api('wall.savePost', {wall_id:viewer_id,post_id:post_id,photo_id:r.id,message:post_message}, photoPosted, ErrorPost);
photo_id